# ArgumentError: undefined class/module when saving record inside record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This may be asked but I didn't know how to search for it, as it looks like a broader topic.

**Problem**

I have a **Post** table that has a field **user_id** (it's a custom column, not association). While saving the post, I accidentally saved `:user_id => @user` instead of `:user_id => @user.id`

Now, I ran into this problem (inside rails console):

When I try to fetch this particular **post** record which has entire user record instead of **user_id**, then I get error **ArgumentError: undefined class/module User**

It doesn't even allow to update the record (I was trying backfill task). I also get this error when I do `Post.all`

What is the issue?

**EDIT**

When I see the record from MySQL, the **user_id** column looks like:

```
!ruby/object:User
  attributes:
    id: 31
    firstname: somename
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Probably you should try executing some raw QL statements to see what's saved in that column. e.g `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE CONDITION")` and see what you get.

Comment: How are you attempting to retrieve the post record?

Comment: @TamerShlash I already saw the user record in the **user_id** field from mysql directly. That is creating problem

Comment: @Abhi what does it look like?

Comment: @TamerShlash It's a big record to be posted in question. Still I have posted some initials of the record

Comment: @cheniel After getting **Post** record's id from MySQL, I tried `Post.where(:id => 234)` to get the record

Comment: @Abhi well, what does the code show: `puts Post.where(:id => 234).first.inspect`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Gives the same error **ArgumentError: undefined class/module User**. It doesn't even allow me to fetch that record.

Comment: have you thr `User` model defined?

Comment: @Abhi then before the code that raises the exception, insert the line: `require 'app/models/user'`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Well that helped but it doesn't look as a clean solution, as I need to require it every time. Even inside (rails c). It would be great if I know why it happened in the first place

Comment: @Abhi if you explain what do you try to do, and wish to get, I'll try to find another.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I'm writing a backfill to revert my mistake, but it stops with the same error in the first line itself `Post.all do |post|`

Comment: @Abhi where is the code line placed?